# Find the divergence of $F=-(x,y)/r^2$ using the definition

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Find the divergence of $F=-(x,y)/r^2$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Don't use this formula $\operatorname{div} F=Px+Qy$ where $F= (P,Q)$; I am not familiar with the definition of divergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean $\vec{F} = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \hat i + \frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \hat j$

div$\vec{F} = \nabla \cdot \vec{F} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\vec{F} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\vec{F}$.

Then we have div$\vec{F} = \frac{-y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{-x^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} = - \frac{x^2 + y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = -\frac{1}{r}$.

Comment: Yes. That 's what I mean. But my F=(-x/r^2,-y/r^2). Also, I know how to get the answer using this formula. I want to get the answer using the definition.

Comment: What definition are you working with?

Comment: The definition of divergence is a limit.